# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation updating database in nuget console

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

So I am self-studying MVC 5 on udemy and I was trying to use code first flow so using NuGet console I want the update command

> update-database
>   and it never worked I search and search but nothing works with the error [image: Exception]

notice: i have checked the connection string and also tried different ways to type it, Used 'EntityFramework\Update-Database'

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear. You either work with Core or full-fat .Net framework, but not both. So you need to remove one of the packages

Comment: thanks really for replying but i have tried this and it makes other errors i also  tried many other things to solve this but different errors keep appearing finally i tried to make a new project and this error

Comment: Error Number:2,State:0,Class:20
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

Comment: i tried to install so many sql and checked the connection and still giving the same error